# Difference between two dates function not working Python

Tags: python

Difference between two date function taken from [Python difference between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248102/python-difference-between-two-dates)

```
def days_between(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d")
    return abs((d2 - d1).days)
```

Trying to return a String as strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series

```
date1 = list(map(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x,'%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), df['Date Created']))
date2 = list(map(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x,'%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), df['Date Completed']))
```

Result to print into new column of DateFrame

```
result1 = days_between(date1, date2)

df['Days to Completion'] = result1
print(df.head())
```

Error given:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ljvw6z\PycharmProjects\AnalysisTest1\dataset.py", line 54, in <module>
    date1 = list(map(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x,'%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), df['Date Created']))
  File "C:\Users\ljvw6z\PycharmProjects\AnalysisTest1\dataset.py", line 54, in <lambda>
    date1 = list(map(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x,'%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), df['Date Created']))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you are getting, the map function requires an integer input instead of the timestamp format, what effectively needs to be done is you converting the datetime to integer first...

You can convert the datetime object to a timetuple, and then use the time.mktime function

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = int(time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple()))
```

Then, Convert it back with:

```
now = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your response. Unfortunately it gave me the following error: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'. I've since found an easier to way to achieve what I'm trying to do using this link - https://bramtunggala.medium.com/a-simple-way-to-finding-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-pandas-179d2714b6c. Thanks for your help :)